# Strange characters showing in MySQL database and on the website

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, character, collation

This is running on Windows Server 2008 R2

MySQL (phpmyadmin) shows

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.5.18
Protocol version: 10
User: -
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 

MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci
```

This is running on XAMPP in Windows 7

MySQL (phpmyadmin) shows

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.1.53-community-log
Protocol version: 10
User: -
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci
```

MySQL charset show UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) MySQL connection collation is utf8_general_ci and the table Collaion is set to utf8_general_ci and in my index.php I've set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_general_ci"/>
```

When I go to localhost/index.php on my Windows 7 machine is shows *plús*
When I go to www.domain.com/index.php which runs from Windows Server 2008 R2 it shows *plÃºs*

Both have the same index.php.

I've followed this tutorial to set my MySQL for Windows Server: [WEBSITE](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/install-phpmyadmin-on-iis7-and-server-2008)

So why does this happen? So far I Know everything is set OK.

Thanks,
F4LLCON

***Broblem solved***

```
utf8_general_ci is not a registered charset for use in HTTP.

Use only UTF-8 in <meta>
```

By user - Dr.Molle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utf8_general_ci` is not a registered charset for use in HTTP.

Use only UTF-8 in `<meta>`

See http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets for a list of available charsets.

Comment: Did this right before reading this but anyways thanks this will fix the problem and I learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Columns can also have a charset / collation that differs from the values specified for server / database / table

This is a create table statement.
col name1 inherits it's charset from the database (utf8 in my case)
col name2 has a carset/collation specified.

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`test` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name2` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: datebase, tables and string columns can have different charset/collations. (all mixed up)

Comment: Oh right, I always set that to utf8_general_ci for every column. 
Well the strange part is that the databases are the same but in Windows 7 localhost/index.php the meta is set to utf8_general_ci. If I set the meta of index.php to UTF8 it shows me pl?s instead of plús and with utf8_general_ci it shows me plús. In windows server 2008 I need to set the meta of index.php to UTF8 to show plús instead of utf8_general_ci. That is strange because the databases are the same. Well problem solved anyways. Thanks